# why most processes have the explorer.exe as their parent process

Tags: windows

I listed the running processes many times and saw that most of them are children to explorer.exe and and the parent of explorer.exe doesn't seem to be running
why this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a user logs in, the explorer process is created by userinit process. Userinit performs some initialization of the user environment (such as running the login script and applying group policies) and then looks in the registry at the Shell value and creates a process to run the system-defined shell – by default, Explorer.exe. Then Userinit exits. This is why Explorer.exe is shown by various process explorers with no parent – its parent has exited. -- refer from
wiki [File_Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer)

[image: windows boot progress]

As you can see from this picture, explorer.exe was started by userinit.exe, and userinit.exe exits at last, so explorer.exe doesn't have parent process.

Because windows uses explorer.exe to start startup processes, all normal processes are children of explorer.exe, unless a child becomes parent less (orphaned) by its parent exiting.

Because all new programs be started by user running in user desktop, they are all explorer's children.

[image: process tree]

[image]